# Resuming a suspended Crime Spree costs Continental coins?

Tags: payday-2

I started a Crime Spree at level 0 and paid 6 Continental Coins for it. I then decided to do something else and suspended the Crime Spree right away.

Later, I wanted to resume the Crime Spree, but the game told me that I did not have enough Continental Coins (I had 5). Does this mean I have to pay Continental Coins not only for starting a spree, but also for resuming one?

Or is this merely a threshold of coins I need to have and they are not actually deducted?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I really needed to **pay** the 6 Continental Coins to resume my Crime Spree of level 0.

However, if the level is greater than 0, no Coins must be spent to resume the Crime Spree.

(This is what I found out, feel free to post a better answer with more information.)

Answer (score 1):

Currently (after update 149), to start or continue a crime spree, it costs half as many continental coins as there are spree points in the crime spree you're starting or continuing.

Crime sprees starting at 0 spree points will be free to start or continue.

If your personal best crime spree was at 250 spree points, you will be able to start a crime spree at 250 points for 125 continental coins. If you failed a mission in some way at a crime spree of 250 points, it would also cost you 125 continental coins to continue it.

Answer (score 0):

**Only if You failed**

If you just completed a mission successfully or none even, you can suspend the spree to resume later at no cost at all.

But if you failed a mission(disconnecting from a mission or actually failing the objective) you will need to pay Coins depending on the current level of your spree to resume.

All rewards accumulated up to the current level can be claimed regardless.

Note that once you selected a mission, returning to main menu is also a fail. The only time you can suspend and resume later at no cost is at the lobby before which you select a mission.